# Sort rows in a dataframe based on highest values in the whole dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, sorting, row

I have a dataframe that has probability values for 3 category columns [A, B, C]. Now I want to sort the rows of this dataframe based on the condition that the row which has the highest probability value in the whole dataframe(irrespective of the columns), should be at the top followed by the row with the second highest probability value and so on.

If someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10,3)))

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   0  1  2
0  9  2  8
1  6  6  9
2  2  4  9
3  2  1  2
4  2  5  3
5  3  4  9
6  8  7  3
7  6  4  1
8  3  3  8
9  7  2  7

In [17]: df.iloc[df.apply(np.max, axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index]
Out[17]:
   0  1  2
5  3  4  9
2  2  4  9
1  6  6  9
0  9  2  8
8  3  3  8
6  8  7  3
9  7  2  7
7  6  4  1
4  2  5  3
3  2  1  2
```